# Call a jquery document ready function from php page

Tags: jquery

Id like to call a jquery function (inside document ready) from php page but with no success.

My php call (first attempt)

```
echo '<script>'; 
echo "ShowBox();";
echo '</script>';
```

My php call (second attempt)

```
echo '<script>'; 
echo "$(function(){ ShowBox(); });";
echo '</script>';
```

Jquery document ready page

```
  $( function() {

       function ShowBox(){
         $('.box').show("slow");
       }

   });
```

How could I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Since php is rendered as html, there's no need to do this.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I tried to call from a php a function that must be in the juery document ready.

Comment: You cannot call php functions from javscript as php runs on the server and javascript runs in the browser, on the client.

Answer (score 0):

add [**js**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) by **[php](http://php.net/)**

```
<?php echo "<script  type='text/javascript'>
           $( function() {
         ShowBox();

   });

   function ShowBox(){
         $('.box').show('slow');
       }
</script>
"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ShowBox(){
         $('.box').show("slow");
       }
</script>

<?php 
  echo '<script>'; 
  echo "jQuery(function(){ ShowBox(); });";
  echo '</script>';
?>
```

Comment: Then you have to add [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) in the php code so the function call after the whole document will get loaded.

Comment: Thanks, is the solution that I decided to use

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <script>
        //Self Executing
        (function($) {
            function ShowBox(){
               $('.box').show("slow");
            }
            ShowBox();
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <div class="box" style="display: none">Box to Show!</div>
</body>
```

But to warn, this isn't how your PHP and JS should work at all really. The only time you will is with a PHP Variable printed onto the Script, for e.g.

```
<script>
   var UserId = <?php echo $UserId; ?>;
</script>
```